# How can I stop dying SO FAST after running into someone decent in Fortnite?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

So I like to play fortnite, and while neither me nor my hardware is too good, I still find it a fun way to connect with my friends, even though i am trash at the game playing on a 25 dollar nintendo switch controller and a crappy monitor, but I also like to play arena, and the thing is, whenever I run into somebody I just die SO FAST! I hear somebody in a building. I crouch over by the door, they jump out behind me, and I can't even turn around to get a shot off before I'm dead. I think I might be able to hold my own to some extent if I can stay alive for more than 2 seconds after shots are fired at me. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason you are dying in Fortnite so fast is because Fortnite is now cross-platform, with every type of device. For example, although you may be playing with Switch players in a normal match, you may come across PC players, who more than likely have better specs and monitors than you. But, if you want to get better at Fortnite, here are some resources that might help you:

1. **3D Aimtrainer** - Helps increase aim with practice
2. [**How to Get Faster Reaction Speed**](https://www.wikihow.com/Improve-Reaction-Speed) - A link that tells how to increase your reaction time, which is crucial for gaming
3. **[PCGamer Best Fortnite Strategies](https://www.gamesradar.com/fortnite-battle-royale-best-weapons-gun-guide/)** - Another article that tells great strategies that significantly increase chances of victory

Of course, many other factors come into play, such as having a good monitor, good console, etc. But this is a good starting point to get better at gaming.

Comment: all gameplay is cross platform, not only arena

Comment: @Topcode Ok, fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

Just practice, you will eventually get better with practice. When i first started i was trash. It took 5 years to get good at the game.

Comment: Hi @manowar, while your answer is not wrong, it is quite generic, which is probably the reason for the downvote(s). Addmitedly, the question itself is not easy to answer and it's probably not a good question for a Q&A format (as evidenced by its low score).